# Creating distance radius along line network from point

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-network-analysis

In QGIS I'm trying to create a 1/4 mile radius (1,320 ft) around a point. I could obviously use buffer, which shows `'as the crow flies'` - but I would like this along with the road network (in green). See below: buffer gives me the circle in blue, I want the irregular shape in green.

[image: example1]

I've tried using Network Analysis (Service Area - from the point), but the results seem way off: the shape seems like a regular diamond, and the length is way more than I'd input. The radius is a 1/4 mile buffer, while the blue lines are the result from running Service Area from the point, even though I'd inputted 1,320 feet.

[image: example2]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Not sure if it makes a difference, but I've been putting in XY coordinates for the starting point.

[[image: xample3]

---

I've figured it out. 
Step 1: processing toolbox > network analysis > service area from point. Easy enough. For some reason the 'distance' is in meters even though all layers are in NAD83 (feet)...?
Step 2: processing toolbox > vector geometry > Concave Hull (k-nearest neighbor).

Comment: hi, are u sure that you can input feet in the travel cost? it's more likely that these are meters.

Comment: You're right it dows look like meters, but the projection is NAD83 (feet)...?

Comment: Taras - I'll look into those, thanks!